# I have a test case in rally. I want to get the name of test folder in which test case exist using java API

Tags: java, rally, code-rally

I tried getting the test case as json object. It will have Test folder information as a uri. How can I get the name of that test folder without hitting this uri again.

When I hit the URI it gives me the `TFxxx`, This is what I need directly..

I tried getting as `jsonObj.get("TestFolder.Name").toString();` which simply returns null.

Any help?

Comment: `jsonObj.getString("TestFolder.Name")` ?

Comment: as `jsonObj.getString("TestFolder.Name")` is null its giving `jsonObj.getString("TestFolder.Name").toString()` also as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below I query for a TestCase that happens to be in a TestFolder, and then traverse to the folder like this:

```
testCaseJsonObject.get("TestFolder").getAsJsonObject().get("Name")
```

Here is a full example that returns TestFolder's name:

```
public class GetTestFolder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        String applicationName = "Example: get Folder of TestCase";
        String projectRef = "/project/12352608219";
        String apiKey = "_abc123";
        RallyRestApi restApi = null;
        try {
            restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),apiKey);
            restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);
            QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
            testCaseRequest.setProject(projectRef);

            testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] {"FormattedID","Name","TestFolder"}));
            testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TC47"));
            testCaseRequest.setScopedDown(false);
            testCaseRequest.setScopedUp(false);

            QueryResponse testCaseResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
            System.out.println("Successful: " + testCaseResponse.wasSuccessful());
            for (int i=0; i<testCaseResponse.getResults().size();i++){
                JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                System.out.println("Name: " + testCaseJsonObject.get("Name") + " FormattedID: " + testCaseJsonObject.get("FormattedID") + " TestFolder: " + testCaseJsonObject.get("TestFolder").getAsJsonObject().get("Name"));

            }
        } finally {
            if (restApi != null) {
                restApi.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```